# Why this hide menu / navigation on scroll works?

Tags: javascript

I've been looking on the internet for vanilla Javascript implementation of hiding menu when scrolled—and found this solution:

```
var previousScroll = window.pageYOffset;    
window.addEventListener( 'scroll', hideMenu );

function hideMenu() {
  var menubar = document.querySelector('.navigation');
  var currentScroll = window.pageYOffset;

  if ( currentScroll > previousScroll) {
    menubar.style.transform = "translateY(-60px)";
  }

  else {
    menubar.style.transform = "";
  }

  previousScroll = currentScroll;

}
```

What I don't understand is, why this works? Why the variable "previousScroll" value could be different with "currentScroll" value?

I've tried to put previousScroll inside the function hideMenu, and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `hideMenu()`is called after the execution of the scroll.
So, `windows.pageYOffset`will return the Y position after scrolling, while the `previousScroll`is the Y **before** scrolling.

That's why it whorks ;)

**Here how does it work step by step :**

**Step 1** (page loaded)

- previousScroll => 0 (top of the page)
- pageYOffset=> 0 (instant Y
  window scroll position)
- currentScroll => ??

**Step 2** (scroll)

- previousScroll => 0 (no changes)
- page is doing scroll (`'scroll'` event is fired)
- pageYOffset => 100 (instant Y window scroll position)
- `'scroll'` callback function is called (`hideMenu()` here)
- update of currentPosition (= pageYOffset = 100)
- update of previousPosition (now is equals to currentPosition)
- ....

Have a look to this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kc1p9pq3/)

Comment: So, shouldn't value be the same? I've tried to show the `previosScroll` and `currentScroll` on a `p` element, and both return the same value when I scrolled.

Comment: @PhilipYoung have a look of the updated answer and jsFiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

The hideMenu function is called when the user scrolls. Therefore, we have access to the current pageYOffset in the page.

We have no way to know where we were before the scroll. That is, unless we kept a reference to it before the 'scroll' event happened.

If you put your variable in the function, previous and current will return the same value and we won't be able to compare them.

Answer (score 0):

1. `currentScroll` is updated when the user scrolls. It represents the current scroll offset.
2. If the user scrolls down (`currentScroll > previousScroll`) then we decide to hide the menu bar. Otherwise we reset its position.
3. At the end, we update `previousScroll` to keep the last scroll position for the next `hideMenu` function call (steps 1 to 3)